# How to check how many compute cores my GPU has under Windows

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows and I'm trying to find out how many compute cores my GPU has. I'm on a laptop with a 3050 Ti, however, it doesn't seem to be the same as a founder's edition 3050 desktop GPU. I can, however, not seem to find the specifications anywhere. Is there a way to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the specifications with GPU-Z:
https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/

Comment: That would show the cores but would it also give compute cores?

Comment: @KonstiLackner CUDA was created by NVIDIA, compute cores is usually referred to in the context of AMD GPUs, difficult to really compare the two. In any case, if you think that GPU-Z helps you then please accept the answer. Greetings from Vienna.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to install GPU-Z but then use it to get the exact name of the GPU which can then be looked up. Note also: CUDA cores seems to be the same as compute cores.